# Apply a custom function to a SQL database based on columns - elegantly

Tags: sql, user-defined-functions

I would like to apply a custom function to a SQL table, and have only found a work-around so far.

I have a table, with different countries and one column representing a value (financial value). I would like to create another column with a transformation of this value: sometimes it will be a flat value, sometimes a percent value (fixed percent), sometimes of percent value (percent based on the value: 1% if less than 1M, 2% if from 1M to 10M, 3% else), all this numbers are different for each country and in an Excel table.

My current solution, which is working, is to create an Excel table with country, function, (functions are "flatValue, pctValue, flatStep"), and parameters (the flat value, or pct, or step) import it to SQL, and match to my input table. Then I do three left merges and calculate the output. It time, I will get the correct output or a NULL, and keep the first non NULL value.
For the step function, I have 5 parameters in my cell (1M, 10M threshold, 1%, 2%, 3%) so I first parse the cell.

This is working but not convenient and ugly. If I want to add more function, it will even be harder to change. Is there a functionaliy in SQL to create some custom functions and apply them to the column. For instance, output = F(financial value, function, parameters). Then I can create some case when in this function.

Comment: Most SQL databases support some version of `CREATE FUNCTION`, but you haven't provided any details about what you are using.

Comment: Please tag the actual SQL version... Postgres? SQL Server? Oracle? MySql?